Why MATLAB is considering this differentiator to be stable?
I have a MATLAB code for differentiator , it last line command isstable determines whether system is stable or not. I was surprised by response of MATLAB as according to my understanding differentiator is unstable system
clc;clear;close all
C=0.1e-6
R=47e3
den=1
num=[-R*C 0]
sys=tf(num,den)
pzmap(sys)
%Comments on stability, 
isstable(sys)


That looks like a trivial FIR filter (1 coefficient, so just applying a gain), not a differentiator.  If your input is bounded, your output will be bounded, so you have BIBO stability.

This also looks like a botched attempt to model a passive differentiator which is essentially a first order high pass which below the crossover looks like a differentiator. IT still is stable since above the crossover, it's flat.

1.-
Short answer: Because a single shunt capacitor (not containing explosives indeed) is always stable.
Hilmar and Walls are both correct.
If you want to make it unstable try
num=1
den=[-R*C 1]
sys=tf(num,den)
pzmap(sys)
%Comments on stability,
isstable(sys)

sys =
 
       -1
  ------------
  0.0047 s - 1
 
Continuous-time transfer function.

 =
  logical
   0

2.-
General Answer
A system with all poles on the left hand side of the plane is always stable.
Read this MIT OW short lecture, just 2 pages
15 TRANSFER FUNCTIONS & STABILITY

